# Gitlab pages always shows 404 error when opening artifacts

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce, gitlab-pages

We use a self hosted gitlab ce (Omnibus-Installation on Ubuntu 22.04) for our project repository. The bundled nginx is disabled, because there are other services running that also use the webserver. nginx configuration is [this one taken from gitlab recipes](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/-/blob/master/web-server/nginx/gitlab-omnibus-ssl-nginx.conf)

Now I want to view the generated html reports from phpunit, sitespeed.io, pa11y-ci, etc. that are stored as artifacts without downloading them first. So I actived gitlab pages, but everytime I click on an html file in the artifacts browser I get the message, that I'm redirected to an external url and when I click on the link I'm getting a 404 error.

gitlab runs under `git.domain.de`, pages url is `glp.domain.de`

Displayed Artifacts-URL on pages looks like this:
`https://project.glp.domain.de/-/shop/-/jobs/5511/artifacts/tests/.phpunit-coverage/report/index.html`

I've enabled gitlab pages in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` with access control and executed `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` without any errors. Pages are enabled in the settings for the project, the project is non-public.

These are all changes I made to the default gitlab configuration in gitlab.rb:

```
grep "^[^#;]" gitlab.rb
external_url 'https://git.domain.de'
gitlab_rails['time_zone'] = 'Europe/Berlin'
gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = ['111.222.333.444', '127.0.0.1']
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['enable'] = false
pages_external_url "https://glp.domain.de/"
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
gitlab_pages['access_control'] = true
alertmanager['flags'] = {
  'cluster.advertise-address' => "127.0.0.1:9093",
}
```

The phpunit-job looks like this:

```
phpunit:
    stage: test
    only:
        - branches
    script:
        - docker exec web ci/run-phpunit.sh
        - grep -o -a -m 1 -h -E "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+% covered" tests/.phpunit-coverage/report/index.html

    coverage: '/^\s*\d+.\d+\% covered/'
    artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
            - tests/.phpunit-coverage/
        expire_in: 1 week
```

We only want to browse the artifacts report, do I nevertheless have to insert a pages stage / job for displaying artifacts via pages?

I've activated verbose logging for pages:
`gitlab_pages['log_verbose'] = true`
but no useful messages show up

Currently I'm running out of ideas, what could be wrong in my setup, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I missed to copy the gitlab-pages configuration file from gitlab to nginx. After I copied /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-pages.conf there, adapted it to our needs and activated it, everything now works as expected.